# Blue Screen of Death caused by Quad Tree Program

Tags: c++, opengl, c-preprocessor, quadtree, bsod

I am writing a Quad tree structure for a planet, that decreases and in increases in detail when you are far away from the quad and close to it receptively. However, I am running into some really serious, and annoying bugs.

I have two preprocessor defined constant that determines the size of the Quad tree (QUAD_WIDTH and QUAD_HEIGHT) when I change the value to anything but 32 (16 or 64 for example) I get a blue screen of death. I am using code::blocks as my IDE, another thing: Whenever I try to debug the program in code::blocks I also get a blue screen of death (Doesn't matter if the constants are 32 or not)

Why is this the case? And how can I fix it.
[image]
***PQuad.cpp***

```
#include "..\include\PQuad.h"
#include "..\include\Color3.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

#define QUAD_WIDTH 32
#define QUAD_HEIGHT 32

#define NUM_OF_CHILDREN 4

#define MAX_DEPTH 4

PQuad::PQuad(FaceDirection face_direction, float planet_radius)  {
    this->built = false;
    this->spherised = false;
    this->face_direction = face_direction;
    this->radius = planet_radius;
    this->planet_centre = glm::vec3(0, 0, 0);
}

PQuad::~PQuad()  {
}

std::vector<PQuad> PQuad::get_children()  {
    return children;
}

bool PQuad::get_built()  {
    return this->built;
}

int PQuad::get_depth()  {
    return this->depth;
}

float *PQuad::get_table()  {
    return tree;
}

float PQuad::get_element_width()  {
    return element_width;
}

glm::vec3 PQuad::get_position()  {
    return position;
}

glm::vec3 PQuad::get_centre()  {
    return centre;
}

void PQuad::get_recursive(glm::vec3 player_pos, std::vector<PQuad*>& out_children)  {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < children.size(); i++)  {
        children[i].get_recursive(player_pos, out_children);
    }

    if (this->should_draw(player_pos) ||
        this->depth == 0)  {
        out_children.emplace_back(this);
    }
}

GLuint PQuad::get_vertexbuffer()  {
    return vbo_vertices;
}

GLuint PQuad::get_colorbuffer()  {
    return vbo_colors;
}

GLuint PQuad::get_normalbuffer()  {
    return vbo_normals;
}

GLuint PQuad::get_elementbuffer()  {
    return ibo_elements;
}

void PQuad::set_parent(PQuad *quad)  {
    this->parent = quad;
}

void PQuad::set_child_index(int child_index)  {
    this->child_index = child_index;
}

void PQuad::set_depth(int depth)  {
    this->depth = depth;
}

void PQuad::set_root(bool root)  {
    this->root = root;
}

void PQuad::calculate_position()  {
    this->element_width = depth == 0 ? 1.0f : parent->get_element_width() / 2.0f;

    float quad_y = child_index / 2 == 0 ? 0 : element_width * QUAD_HEIGHT - element_width;
    float quad_x = child_index % 2 == 0 ? 0 : element_width * QUAD_WIDTH - element_width;

    if (this->depth != 0)  {
        quad_x += parent->get_position().x;
        quad_y += parent->get_position().y;
    }

    this->position = glm::vec3(quad_x, quad_y, 0);
}

void PQuad::construct()  {
    if (!this->built)  {
        std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices;
        std::vector<glm::vec3> normals;
        std::vector<Color3> colors;
        std::vector<GLushort> elements;

        construct_vertices(&vertices, &colors);
        construct_elements(&elements);
        spherise(&vertices, &normals);
        construct_normals(&vertices, &elements, &normals);

        construct_buffers(&vertices, &colors, &elements, &normals);

        float distance = radius;

        if (!spherised)  {
            distance = QUAD_WIDTH;
        }

        construct_depth_table(distance);

        this->built = true;
    }
}

void PQuad::construct_depth_table(float distance)  {
    tree[0] = -1;

    for (int i = 1; i < MAX_DEPTH; i++)  {
        tree[i] = distance;

        distance /= 2.0f;
    }
}

void PQuad::construct_children()  {
    calculate_position();

    if (depth < (int)MAX_DEPTH)  {
        children.reserve((int)NUM_OF_CHILDREN);

        for (int i = 0; i < (int)NUM_OF_CHILDREN; i++)  {
            children.emplace_back(PQuad(this->face_direction, this->radius));
            PQuad *child = &children.back();

            child->set_depth(depth + 1);
            child->set_child_index(i);
            child->set_parent(this);

            child->construct_children();
        }
    } else {
        leaf = true;
    }
}

void PQuad::construct_vertices(std::vector<glm::vec3> *vertices, std::vector<Color3> *colors)  {
    vertices->reserve(QUAD_WIDTH * QUAD_HEIGHT);

    for (int y = 0; y < QUAD_HEIGHT; y++)  {
        for (int x = 0; x < QUAD_WIDTH; x++)  {
            switch (face_direction)  {
                case YIncreasing:
                    vertices->emplace_back(glm::vec3(position.x + x * element_width, QUAD_HEIGHT - 1, -(position.y + y * element_width)));
                    break;
                case YDecreasing:
                    vertices->emplace_back(glm::vec3(position.x + x * element_width, 0, -(position.y + y * element_width)));
                    break;
                case XIncreasing:
                    vertices->emplace_back(glm::vec3(QUAD_WIDTH - 1, position.y + y * element_width, -(position.x + x * element_width)));
                    break;
                case XDecreasing:
                    vertices->emplace_back(glm::vec3(0, position.y + y * element_width, -(position.x + x * element_width)));
                    break;
                case ZIncreasing:
                    vertices->emplace_back(glm::vec3(position.x + x * element_width, position.y + y * element_width, 0));
                    break;
                case ZDecreasing:
                    vertices->emplace_back(glm::vec3(position.x + x * element_width, position.y + y * element_width, -(QUAD_WIDTH - 1)));
                    break;
            }

            // Position the bottom, right, front vertex of the cube from being (0,0,0) to (-16, -16, 16)
            (*vertices)[vertices->size() - 1] -= glm::vec3(QUAD_WIDTH / 2.0f, QUAD_WIDTH  / 2.0f, -(QUAD_WIDTH / 2.0f));

            colors->emplace_back(Color3(255.0f, 255.0f, 255.0f, false));
        }
    }

    switch (face_direction)  {
        case YIncreasing:
            this->centre = glm::vec3(position.x + QUAD_WIDTH / 2.0f, QUAD_HEIGHT - 1, -(position.y + QUAD_HEIGHT / 2.0f));
            break;
        case YDecreasing:
            this->centre = glm::vec3(position.x + QUAD_WIDTH / 2.0f, 0, -(position.y + QUAD_HEIGHT / 2));
            break;
        case XIncreasing:
            this->centre = glm::vec3(QUAD_WIDTH - 1, position.y + QUAD_HEIGHT / 2.0f, -(position.x + QUAD_WIDTH / 2.0f));
            break;
        case XDecreasing:
            this->centre = glm::vec3(0, position.y + QUAD_HEIGHT / 2.0f, -(position.x + QUAD_WIDTH / 2.0f));
            break;
        case ZIncreasing:
            this->centre = glm::vec3(position.x + QUAD_WIDTH / 2.0f, position.y + QUAD_HEIGHT / 2.0f, 0);
            break;
        case ZDecreasing:
            this->centre = glm::vec3(position.x + QUAD_WIDTH / 2.0f, position.y + QUAD_HEIGHT / 2.0f, -(QUAD_HEIGHT - 1));
            break;
    }

    this->centre -= glm::vec3(QUAD_WIDTH / 2.0f, QUAD_WIDTH  / 2.0f, -(QUAD_WIDTH / 2.0f));
}

void PQuad::construct_elements(std::vector<GLushort> *elements)  {
    int index = 0;

    elements->reserve((QUAD_WIDTH - 1) * (QUAD_HEIGHT - 1) * 6);

    for (int y = 0; y < QUAD_HEIGHT - 1; y++)  {
        for (int x = 0; x < QUAD_WIDTH - 1; x++)  {
            GLushort bottom_left = x + y * QUAD_WIDTH;
            GLushort bottom_right = (x + 1) + y * QUAD_WIDTH;
            GLushort top_left = x + (y + 1) * QUAD_WIDTH;
            GLushort top_right = (x + 1) + (y + 1) * QUAD_WIDTH;

            elements->emplace_back(top_left);
            elements->emplace_back(bottom_right);
            elements->emplace_back(bottom_left);

            elements->emplace_back(top_left);
            elements->emplace_back(top_right);
            elements->emplace_back(bottom_right);
        }
    }
}

void PQuad::construct_normals(std::vector<glm::vec3> *vertices, std::vector<GLushort> *elements, std::vector<glm::vec3> *normals)  {
    normals->reserve(QUAD_WIDTH * QUAD_HEIGHT);

    for (int i = 0; i < elements->size() / 3; i++)  {
         int index1 = elements->at(i * 3);
         int index2 = elements->at(i * 3 + 1);
         int index3 = elements->at(i * 3 + 2);

         glm::vec3 side1 = vertices->at(index1) - vertices->at(index3);
         glm::vec3 side2 = vertices->at(index1) - vertices->at(index2);
         glm::vec3 normal = glm::cross(side1, side2);
         normal = glm::normalize(normal);

         normals->emplace_back(normal);
         normals->emplace_back(normal);
         normals->emplace_back(normal);
    }
}

void PQuad::spherise(std::vector<glm::vec3> *vertices, std::vector<glm::vec3> *normals)  {
    for (int i = 0; i < QUAD_WIDTH * QUAD_HEIGHT; i++)  {
        glm::vec3 normal = glm::normalize(vertices->at(i) - planet_centre);

        (*vertices)[i] = (float)(radius) * normal;
    }

    glm::vec3 normal = glm::normalize(centre - planet_centre);

    centre = normal * (float)(radius);

    this->spherised = true;
}

void PQuad::construct_buffers(std::vector<glm::vec3> *vertices, std::vector<Color3> *colors, std::vector<GLushort> *elements, std::vector<glm::vec3> *normals)  {
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo_vertices);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_vertices);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3) * vertices->size(), &((*vertices)[0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo_colors);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_colors);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Color3) * colors->size(), &((*colors)[0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo_normals);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_normals);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3) * normals->size(), &((*normals)[0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &ibo_elements);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo_elements);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLushort) * elements->size(), &((*elements)[0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

float distance3(glm::vec3 v1, glm::vec3 v2)  {
    return sqrt(pow(abs(v1.x - v2.x), 2) + pow(abs(v1.y - v2.y), 2) + pow(abs(v1.z - v2.z), 2));
}

bool PQuad::should_draw(glm::vec3 player_position)  {
    float distance = distance3(player_position, centre);

    if (distance < tree[depth])  {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Well, your program shouldn't directly cause it. It should typically be running in a [ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(computer_security)) that doesn't cause blue screens on failure (unless it's a driver or something and you need that extra push down). It is peculiar if it's consistent, though, and the information given on the blue screen would be a good start. I believe you can configure your BIOS or something to not instantly restart on blue screens.

Comment: When you say blue screen of death; you mean... blue screen of death?  your computer Stops?  wow.

Comment: Yup, I get a "SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION". I'll run the program again and take a photo...

Comment: @chris Just updated my question (with a photo).

Answer (score 6):

A blue screen of death should be just impossible to reach from a regular user space program... no matter what you do.

However unfortunately it's easy to bump into this kind of system level bug when writing software that interacts heavily with device drivers because they are software too, and they are not bug free (and a bug in a device driver can take down the whole system with a BSOD).

The meaning is that you are making some call to OpenGL with wrong parameters, and that the driver of your video card has a bug and instead of detecting the problem and returning a failure code, it just takes down the machine.

You may try to use a log of the operations, writing to a file each single step so after you get a BSOD and reboot you can check what was the last command written to the file. Note that you should open the file in *append*, write the log line and then close the file. Not even this gives you a 100% guarantee the content of the file will have been written really to the disk when you get the BSOD, but IMO in this case the probability should be high. A better alternative would be just sending log messages over the serial line or using the network to another computer.

It may be a difficult problem to track and solve.

Another option would be using a different OpenGL implementation (like Mesa). May be with another implementation calls are checked better and you can spot what is the call with wrong parameters.

It could even be that your code is just triggering a bug in the video driver and your code is not doing anything wrong. This should be your **last** thought however.

Comment: Sensible answer. For some reason, it never clicked with me that OpenGL was being used.

Comment: I just tried this program on my laptop, no BSOD. So, I guess it's just the device driver. Thanks :)

Comment: @chris: video drivers are in my experience a weak link. They are very complex and I found that focus is more on performance than on correctness in handling edge cases. And this is not just a windows thing... I was able to unintentionally take down my linux machine from Javascript just by using strange matrix transforms with canvas drawing...

Comment: @6502, You're making me want to try to BSOD something via DirectX.

Comment: @Darestium: apparently you have a strange concept of "last thought". My bet is that your code is doing something wrong and that simply you now don't see the symptom.

Comment: @chris: there is no need even to go that far. In a windows system you can get BSODs even by liberal playing with `CreateDIBSection` (or you could get that in the past... it's long I'm not working heavily under windows).

Comment: @6502, Gah, your other response reminded me of a *The Old New Thing* post about a graphics card that responded yes to all capability questions, but I can't find it now.

Comment: @6502, Found it :) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/11/71307.aspx#71354

Comment: @chris: Yes. Other people software can have bugs. Even the OS can have bugs. But unless you can find **exactly** what is the bug (by producing a minimal repeatable case of a correct call that triggers the problem) then you're not entitled to tell the bug is in other people code. Assuming that when you have a problem the bug is in other people's code is just placing a pretty low limit on where your ability as a programmer can get. A BSOD is for sure a symptom of a bug in some other people code (you can't get there; it's in the contract)... but this doesn't prove your code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer is quite simple. There is something really wrong with the debugger in Code::Blocks on Windows. I have seen it blue screen multiple systems. Switch to using output statements or another IDE.

Comment: Weird, I've never had gdb blue screen on me, but then again, I haven't used it much.

Comment: It's not necessarily GDB itself; it's more how Code::Blocks uses it. I've seen it crash on a friend's Windows system. The OpenGL *could* be related. (I use OpenGL myself.) I just know this to be a common issue with CB.

Comment: this seems unlikely as he always sees the BSOD, not only when debugging.

Comment: Yeah, it could be anything, really. I am in the process of replacing my own motherboard because of random BSOD issues. T_T

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw, This is one of the issues, even a "hello world" program crashes my computer when I try to debug it in c::b. I loath to switch to another IDE, but I guess it's the only way short of constructing a new computer.